# Getting XML with PHP: how to get attributes from 2 nodes with same name

Tags: php, xml

I am getting attributes from XML nodes and saving them to variables with a for loop as such:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $group = $xml->Competition->Round[0]->Event[$i][Group];
    if($group == "MTCH"){
        $eventid = $xml->Competition->Round[0]->Event[$i][EventID];
        $eventname = $xml->Competition->Round[0]->Event[$i][EventName];
        $teamaname = $xml->Competition->Round[0]->Event[$i]->EventSelections[0][EventSelectionName];
        $teambname = $xml->Competition->Round[0]->Event[$i]->EventSelections[1][EventSelectionName];
        echo "<br/>" . $eventid . ": " . $eventname . ", " .  $teamaname . "VS" . $teambname;
    }//IF
}//FOR
```

I can save each `Event[EventID]` and each `Event[EventName]` but I cannot get the `EventSelections[EventSelectionNames]` to save.

I am guessing this is because there are multiple (2) `<EventSelection>s` for each `<Event>`, this is why I tried to get them individually uising `[0]` and `[1]`.

The part of the XML file in question looks like:

```
<Event EventID="1008782" EventName="Collingwood v Fremantle" Venue="" EventDate="2014-03-14T18:20:00" Group="MTCH">
  <Market Type="Head to Head" EachWayPlaces="0">
    <EventSelections BetSelectionID="88029974" EventSelectionName="Collingwood">
      <Bet Odds="2.10" Line=""/>
    </EventSelections>
    <EventSelections BetSelectionID="88029975" EventSelectionName="Fremantle">
      <Bet Odds="1.70" Line=""/>
    </EventSelections>
  </Market>
</Event>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to save the `EventSelectionName`s to variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping and checking for `$group`, use `xpath` to select data directly:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$group = $xml->xpath("/Event[@Group = 'MTCH']")[0];
echo "ID: $group[EventID], name: $group[EventName]" . PHP_EOL;
```

If there are **always** two `<EventSelections>`, you can:

```
echo "Team A: " . $group->Market->EventSelections[0]['EventSelectionName']" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Team B: " . $group->Market->EventSelections[1]['EventSelectionName']" . PHP_EOL;
```

Otherwise, use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($group->Market->EventSelections as $es)
    $teamnames[] = $es['EventSelectionName'];

echo "There are " . count($teamnames) . "Teams:" . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($teamname as $teamname) echo $teamname . PHP_EOL;
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/105642

**Note**:

The `[0]` at the end of the code-line starting with `$group = $xml->xpath...`requires PHP >= 5.4. If you are on a lower version, update PHP or use:

```
$group = $xml->xpath("/Event[@Group = 'MTCH']");
$group = $group[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Michi's answer is more correct and better coded but I also found the adding the node 'Market' to my code worked as well:

```
$teamaname = $xml->Competition->Round[0]->Event[$i]->Market->EventSelections[0][EventSelectionName];
$teambname = $xml->Competition->Round[0]->Event[$i]->Market->EventSelections[1][EventSelectionName];
```

Comment: That's what I struggled with, too! I had simply not realized the `<Market>`-node and wondered why I wasn't getting the expected result - until it finally hit me ;-)